# My View is not passing the integer from my input to the controller, how can I fix it?

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, model-binding, nopcommerce

Hey Guys I have the following problem: My View is not passing on my integer that I input into my search field, so it always just returns as if I entered 0

[image: For example here I enter 443 as my OrderId]

[image: Yet I always get page 404 not found and in the Url it shows as if I entered 0]

```
 <form class="form-group" asp-controller="AttestationEditor" asp-action="SearchForAttestationByOrderId" asp-route-id="@Model.OrderId" method="post">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="label-wrapper">
                                        <label class="control-label" id="SearchByOrderId">Order ID</label>
                                        <div title="The Order Id is used to find an individual Order from which the Buyer Name and Purchase Reason can be identified. Please note that Orders that do not have the status 'delivered' will be automatically non-editable " data-toggle="tooltip" class="ico-help">
                                            <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.OrderId" />
                                    <!--type="submit" //add this to button when functionality is needed again, leave for testing view-->
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-search" onclick="showPanel('panelValues');">
                                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                        @T("Admin.Common.Search") by Order ID
                                    </button>
                                </div>

                            </form>
```

my form part from my View file

```
[HttpGet("/[area]/[controller]/[action]/{orderId:int}")]
    public IActionResult SearchForAttestationByOrderId(int orderId)
    {
        //has an order been found? if not, give reason
        //if order is found, we redirect towards DisplayBuyerName as no view output is needed at this state (an Order itself is not useful for this feature)
        //This action purely has the purpose of adding validation logic
        Order? order = _orderService.GetOrderById(orderId);

        if (order == null)
        {
            return NotFound(orderId);
        }

        else if (order.OrderStatus != OrderStatus.Complete)
        {
            return CannotEdit(orderId, $"{nameof(order.OrderStatus)} is '{order.OrderStatus}', but '{OrderStatus.Complete}' is required.");
        }

        else if (order.PaymentStatus != PaymentStatus.Paid)
        {
            return CannotEdit(orderId, $"{nameof(order.PaymentStatus)} is '{order.PaymentStatus}', but '{PaymentStatus.Paid}' is required.");
        }

        else if (order.ShippingStatus != ShippingStatus.Delivered)
        {
            return CannotEdit(orderId, $"{nameof(order.ShippingStatus)} is '{order.ShippingStatus}', but '{ShippingStatus.Delivered}' is required.");
        }


        return RedirectToAction("DisplayBuyerName", new { id = orderId }); ;
    }
```

and my controller action where Im trying to pass the orderId that I input into the search field

```
public class AttestationEditorModel
{
    //Here we can add validation, like that BuyerName only accepts letters from A-z and no special symbols
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Order ID. Must be a number.")]
    
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="This field cannot be empty!")]
```

...}

and there the start from my model file

much thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @odod,  Please share more code to us. Only change  `method="post"`  to `method="get"` works fine. But  i cannot reproduce the same issue with id=0. It will always send default id . The default id is what the view firstly rendered value for the input. Do you set the default id?

Answer (score 2):

Why did you were used `asp-route-id="@Model.OrderId"`? I think this is not necessary.

And I want to say you use `methode="post"` in your form and in your controller you used Httpget... this is a mistake.

Comment: Hi thank you so much, still a newbie. Gonna fix those mistakes and see if it works

Comment: Hi, I changed it but it still does not work. I added httppost to controller and delete httpget, am I still doing something wrong?

Comment: So now you should change your action... 
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SearchForAttestationByOrderId(AttestationEditorModel model)

Comment: but listen if you want to search in your data list you should change your method form to "get" and use [Httpget] and just search in google "How can I pass data from view to controller from get method in asp.net"

Comment: but I say this to you please try it first and then go and search...
for search after change your type to get (your method in form and your [HttpPost]) 
set name for your input for example <input type="Text" name="search">
and then com to your action and set this parameter 
public IActionResult SearchForAttestationByOrderId(string search)
after geting int you can changeing to int...
and don't write [HttpGet("/[area]/[controller]/[action]/{orderId:int}")],
just write [HttpGet].
good luck.

Comment: hey thanks man, it works now :) really apprecciate it